# iOS 7 MPMoviePlayerController change name of Done button

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, ios7

In iOS 6 we change name of done button in MPMoviePlayerController next way:

```
    id mpBarAppearance = [UIBarButtonItem appearanceWhenContainedIn:[MPMoviePlayerViewController class], nil];
    [mpBarAppearance setTitle:@"ГОТОВО"];
    [mpBarAppearance setTitlePositionAdjustment:UIOffsetMake(1.5f, 1.f) forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
    [mpBarAppearance setTitlePositionAdjustment:UIOffsetMake(1.5f, 1.f) forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsLandscapePhone];
```

Now in iOS 7 this crash app, under debbug it no raise exception and I cann't even understand why ?

Answer (score 0):

It's because you can't use the appearance proxy to customise the title of `UIBarButtonItem`s. Otherwise, all the bar buttons contained in the given parent would be named the same. You can customise other appearance parameters such as the background images, title position and so on.

The appearance proxy reference for `UIBarButtonItem` can be found [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIBarButtonItem_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007519-CH3-SW52)