# iOS Video Player Done Button

Tags: ios, mpmovieplayercontroller

Can I change the iOS video player **Done** button title to my custom title?

I searched for it but did not find any helpful answer. Any help would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An educated guess [based on some quick research](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18998317/ios-7-mpmovieplayercontroller-change-name-of-done-button) says - no, you can't. You can create your own video player control however.

The thing is you can't directly control the `MPMoviewPlayer` view's `UIToolbar`, therefore, you can't edit it anyhow.